# default cakePhp .htaccess file does not work with redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I just installed an Ubuntu web server with apache2. I upload a CakePHP project. I also activated rewrite_mod.

```
# sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

When navigating to www.mysite.ch/pierre/contacts it states:

> Not found
>   The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.

In my local webserver, it works and I can see the contact page

If I remove my project and add a file phpinfo.php with the function phpinfo(), it show information about the server configuration and I do not have a message "not found"

I suspect that my redirection does not work.
What do you think?

Which are the basic step to make an Apache2 server working with an .htaccess file?

Here are is my .htaccess file (it is the default cakephp file, I have not changed it)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule  ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
   RewriteRule  (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my httpd_conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/metauxch/httpdoc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /pierre /var/www/vhosts/pierre/httpdoc
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/pierre/httpdoc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        allow from All
</Directory>
```

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All** in httpd_conf file

Enable mode rewrite,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

restart apache,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I forgetten to write but I did it

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo servive apache2 restart
```

This is done.

I also change this AllowOverride All

The probleme, now is when I enter

> http://eflumpc38.epfl.ch/pierre/contacts

It state that te controller pierre (CakePHP) is missing. While pierre is the root and contacts is the controller.

Second point, when I clink on the Contact (root/contacts/)
I have a such URL

> http://eflumpc38.epfl.ch/vhosts/pierre/httpdoc/contacts

instead of

> http://eflumpc38.epfl.ch/pierre/contacts

Does some thing is wrong here

```
Alias /pierre /var/www/vhosts/pierre/httpdoc
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/pierre/httpdoc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        allow from All
</Directory>
```

When I upload the same CakePHP projet on my usual provider, I do not have this issue.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

try this solution.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
CakePHP app directory (will be copied to the top directory of your application by bake):

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    /webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
CakePHP webroot directory (will be copied to your application’s web root by bake):

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, none of them work. Itried all, them of them. I got no good result :o(